# Get Slack user name through oAuth API

Tags: api, oauth, slack-api

I'm using th eSlack oAuth API to integrate my app with Slack. Following [these instructions](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) I do the following:

1. Call https://slack.com/oauth/authorize passing my client_id, and the scope "identify,read,post -> I get a code
2. Call https://slack.com/api/oauth.access with the id, secret, code -> I get an access token
3. I now want to get the user's handle (name) -> looking at the [user.info documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info), I need to provide my token, and the user's ID - which I don't have.

Where/how am I supposed to get the user's ID? What am I missing?

Comment: If you can Elevate the scope to include 'Client' permissions, The [rtm.start](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start) method will return the User's ID under the 'self' group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have access to this information in the [auth.test](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) endpoint. It will also return the team id, user id, and user's name.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like just what I needed!

Comment: The response from [oauth.access](https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.access) in most cases now also includes the user ID of the authorizing user.